# How to Control agents Population based in their attributes

Tags: java, controls, anylogic, agent

1)I have Population of agents having gender as Attribute (Male and female) how can i pass agents based on their gender to different Queues after Output Box?
2) or how to Access individual agents from Population so that their movement can be Controlled individually based on their Attributes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an option list for that. Right-click on your project name and create a new option list.

[image]

Then, fill it in the following way:
[image]

Then, in the agent type window, add a variable of type `Gender` and depending on your model design assign a value to it. In the image below, I am randomly assigning half as Males and half as females.

[image]

Now, in your main window, in the select output condition, write the following:
[image]

[image]

This will send males to the first queue and females to the second queue.